# How to limit the SoC in Optimal control?

Tags: python, optimization, controls, gekko

I'm trying to build this physiological model. I want to model athlete recovery, this is similar to an Electric Car state of charge.
I'm unsure how to limit the 100% SoC.

The issue I'm having is that the problem gets very large since I need to get the previous SoC to measure the current Soc. Furthermore, I'm not sure how to model the fact that the discharge rate is not the same as the charge rate.
Thank you

```py
#discharging
W'Exp = (P - CP) * dt                     
soc = soc - W'Exp                       
#If the Power for the data point is below CP or CV, W' is reconstituted:
W'Rec = (CP - P) * dt                            
Rate = (W' - W'Bal) / W'                         
soc = soc + W'Rec * Rate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a Gekko implementation of the simple energy storage model found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S030626191500402X) as an [example problem](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/PeriodicBoundaryConditions). You may be able to modify this model for the athlete.

[image: periodic]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

t = np.linspace(0, 24, 24*3+1)
m.time = t

m.options.SOLVER   = 1
m.options.IMODE    = 6
m.options.NODES    = 3
m.options.CV_TYPE  = 1
m.options.MAX_ITER = 300

p = m.FV()           # production
p.STATUS = 1
s = m.Var(100, lb=0) # storage inventory
store = m.SV()       # store energy rate
vy = m.SV(lb=0)      # store slack variable
recover = m.SV()     # recover energy rate
vx = m.SV(lb=0)      # recover slack variable

eps = 0.7

d = m.MV(-20*np.sin(np.pi*t/12)+100)

m.periodic(s)

m.Equations([p + recover/eps - store >= d,
             p - d == vx - vy,
             store == p - d + vy,
             recover == d - p + vx,
             s.dt() == store - recover/eps,
             store * recover <= 0])
m.Minimize(p)

m.solve(disp=True)

#%% Visualize results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1, sharex=True)

ax = axes[0]
ax.plot(t, store, 'C3-', label='Store Rate')
ax.plot(t, recover, 'C0-.', label='Recover Rate')

ax = axes[1]
ax.plot(t, d, 'k-', label='Electricity Demand')
ax.plot(t, p, 'C3--', label='Power Production')

ax = axes[2]
ax.plot(t, s, 'C2-', label='Energy Inventory')

ax = axes[3]
ax.plot(t, vx, 'C2-', label='$S_1$')
ax.plot(t, vy, 'C3--', label='$S_2$')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (hr)')

for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5), \
              loc='center left', frameon=False)
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_xlim(0, 24)
    loc = mtick.MultipleLocator(base=6)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, I guess SOC is a variable. The upper and lower bound of a variable can be set as follows:

```
m = GEKKO()    
SOC = m.Var(10, lb=0, ub=100)
```

10 is the initial value of SOC.
For your second problem, are `P, CP, W'Bal` given?