# How to update Gekko variable dynamically

Tags: gekko

The following snippet represents the charging and discharging of battery in a simple energy system. The demand load is fulfilled via renewable energy generation (RE in the code) and the energy discharged from battery. Objective function maximizes total income of the system. My understanding is that for each data set (demand, renewable, price), the battery's state of charge (SOC) is calculated and updated (B_SOC in the code). The SOC is bounded from upper side via the battery capacity value. Therefore, for each data set, the calculated value of the SOC is compared with the battery capacity to select the minimum value as SOC[t]=min (SOC[t], battery capacity). For the next data set, the latest SOC[t] should be considered. The "B_Bound" variable is defined to get the results of min (SOC[t], battery capacity). My first question is about updating the value of B_SOC for each data set. I placed another variable (B_SOC_test) to show the following point. When the battery is charging (or discharging), its value is added (subtracted) of the B_SOC_test variable (NOT from B_SOC), while the B_Bound is assigned to B_SOC for each data set (please the image below). My second question is about the I_disch which is a binary variable. Its output value for the third data set is B_disch2=[1.4295102702e-21]. I am not sure if I need to change an option in the m.solver_options? Thank you so much for your help.

[image: values]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import sys

Inp_Data=pd.DataFrame([[3.61,4.55,13],[3.6,5.47,11],[3.47,6.02,11],[3.99,6.12,12],[4.45,3.69,14],[3.78,2.89,15],[3.72,2.02,18]])
col_name=list(Inp_Data)
row=len(Inp_Data)
Demand=Inp_Data.loc[:,col_name[0]].tolist()
RE=Inp_Data.loc[:,col_name[1]].tolist()
Price=Inp_Data.loc[:,col_name[2]].tolist()

#Battery Specifications
Battery_capacity=6 #kW-h
Battery_Initial_capacity=2.4

Big_M=1000000000000
epsilon=sys.float_info.epsilon

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.options.SOLVER=1

m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1e-100', \
                    'minlp_integer_leaves 2']


#Battery Specifications
Battery_capacity=6 #kW-h
Battery_Initial_capacity=2.4

B_ch=[m.Var(lb=0) for t in range(row)]
B_disch=[m.Var(lb=0) for t in range(row)]
B_Bound=[m.Var(lb=0) for t in range(row)]
B_SOC=[m.Var(lb=0) for t in range(row)]
B_SOC_test=[m.Var(lb=0) for t in range(row)]

I_ch=[m.Var(integer=True,lb=0,ub=1) for t in range(row)]
I_disch=[m.Var(integer=True,lb=0,ub=1) for t in range(row)]

#Objective function
c = [None]*row
for t in range(row):
    c[t] = (Demand[t]*Price[t])

m.Equations(RE[t]-I_ch[t]*B_ch[t]+I_disch[t]*B_disch[t]==Demand[t] for t in range(row))

#Energy Storage constraints
m.Equations(B_SOC[t]==Battery_Initial_capacity+I_ch[t]*B_ch[t]-I_disch[t]*B_disch[t] for t in range(1))
m.Equations(B_SOC[t]==B_SOC[t-1]+I_ch[t]*B_ch[t]-I_disch[t]*B_disch[t] for t in range(1,row))

#First Question
m.Equations(B_SOC_test[t]==Battery_Initial_capacity+I_ch[t]*B_ch[t]-I_disch[t]*B_disch[t] for t in range(1))
m.Equations(B_SOC_test[t]==B_SOC_test[t-1]+I_ch[t]*B_ch[t]-I_disch[t]*B_disch[t] for t in range(1,row))

m.Equations((I_ch[t]+I_disch[t])<=1 for t in range(row))
m.Equations((B_ch[t]*B_disch[t])==0 for t in range(row))

# B_Bound=[m.if3(Battery_capacity-B_SOC[t],Battery_capacity,B_SOC[t]) for t in range(row)] #Line 62
m.Equations(B_Bound[t]<=B_SOC[t] for t in range(row)) #Line 63
m.Equations(B_Bound[t]<=Battery_capacity for t in range(row)) # Line 64

B_SOC=[B_Bound[t] for t in range(row)]

m.Maximize(m.sum(c))

# m.open_folder()
m.solve(disp=True)


print('Results')
for t in range(row):
    print('I_ch{}={} I_disch{}={} B_ch{}={}  B_disch{}={}  B_SOC{}={} B_Bound{}={} B_SOC_test{}={}'.format(t,I_ch[t].value,t,I_disch[t].value,t,B_ch[t].value,t,B_disch[t].value,t,B_SOC[t].value,t,B_Bound[t].value,t,B_SOC_test[t].value))

print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of `B_SOC` and `B_SOC_test` are different because of the line:

```py
B_SOC=[B_Bound[t] for t in range(row)]
```

that overwrites the definition of `B_SOC` to be equal to `B_Bound`. Equations must be posted implicitly in Gekko. There are a few related questions that may help:

- [How to limit the SoC in Optimal control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766375/how-to-limit-the-soc-in-optimal-control)
- [How to optimize the electric vehicle charging cost using Gekko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74234285/how-to-optimize-the-electric-vehicle-charging-cost-using-gekko)
- [I want to know python gekko optimization solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74416838/i-want-to-know-python-gekko-optimization-solve/74483655#74483655)

For the second question, binary or integer values have `minlp_integer_tol` that is default 1.0e-2. It is the amount that a candidate solution variable can deviate from an integer solution and still be considered an integer. The value `1.4295102702e-21` is within that tolerance so it reports it as an integer (binary) solution. Even if you set `minlp_integer_tol` to zero, it may still report a small non-integer value deviation because of machine precision.

Comment: Thank you John for your comment and the links. They were very useful. Based on the links, I noticed that I do not need the binary variables and can simply model the problem. To solve the SOC[0], I added one row with zero values in the beginning of my data. I also added the correct version down this text.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the links, I noticed that I do not need the binary variables and can simply model the problem. To solve the `SOC[0]`, I added one row with zero values in the beginning of my data.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import sys

Inp_Data=pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0],[3.61,4.55,13],[3.6,5.47,11],[3.47,6.02,11],[3.99,6.12,12],[4.45,3.69,14],[3.78,2.89,15],[3.72,2.02,18]])
col_name=list(Inp_Data)
row=len(Inp_Data)
Demand=Inp_Data.loc[:,col_name[0]].tolist()
RE=Inp_Data.loc[:,col_name[1]].tolist()
Price=Inp_Data.loc[:,col_name[2]].tolist()

#Battery Specifications
Battery_capacity=6 #kW-h
Battery_Initial_capacity=2.4

Big_M=1000000000000
epsilon=sys.float_info.epsilon

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.options.SOLVER=1

m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1e-100', \
                    'minlp_integer_leaves 2']


#Battery Specifications
Battery_capacity=6 #kW-h
Battery_Initial_capacity=2.4

B_ch=[m.Var(lb=0) for t in range(row)]
B_disch=[m.Var(lb=0) for t in range(row)]
B_SOC=[m.Var(lb=0,ub=Battery_capacity) for t in range(row)]
B_SOC[0]=Battery_Initial_capacity

#Objective function
c = [None]*row
for t in range(row):
    c[t] = (Demand[t]*Price[t])

m.Equations(RE[t]-B_ch[t]+B_disch[t]==Demand[t] for t in range(1,row))
for t in range(1,row):
    B_SOC[t]=m.if3(m.if3(Battery_capacity-(B_SOC[t-1]+B_ch[t]-B_disch[t]),Battery_capacity,B_SOC[t-1]+B_ch[t]-B_disch[t]),0,m.if3(Battery_capacity-(B_SOC[t-1]+B_ch[t]-B_disch[t]),Battery_capacity,B_SOC[t-1]+B_ch[t]-B_disch[t]))

m.Equations(B_ch[t]*B_disch[t]==0 for t in range(row))

m.Maximize(m.sum(c))

# m.open_folder()
m.solve(disp=True)


print('Results')
for t in range(1,row):
    print('B_ch{}={}  B_disch{}={}  B_SOC{}={} '.format(t,B_ch[t].value,t,B_disch[t].value,t,B_SOC[t].value))

print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```